# Webpack : Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined, No output files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Using `webpack > 5` version. Below is my `appDevMiddleware.js`congifuration

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

function createWebpackMiddleware(compiler, publicPath) {
return webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    // noInfo: true,
    publicPath,
    // silent: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
});
}

module.exports = function addDevMiddlewares(app, webpackConfig) {
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
const middleware = createWebpackMiddleware(compiler, webpackConfig.output.publicPath);

app.use(middleware);
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

// Since webpackDevMiddleware uses memory-fs internally to store build
// artifacts, we use it instead
const fs = middleware.fileSystem;

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html'), (err, file) => {
    if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    } else {
        res.send(file.toString());
    }
    });
});
};
```

When i do `npm start` of my React App, i'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined
at D:\master-instore-dashboard\server\middlewares\addDevMiddlewares.js:29:8
```

This is exactly showing here

```
fs.readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html'), (err, file) => {
```

I will have to somehow use the `promises` for readFile which is something like `const { readFile } = require('fs').promises`

How should i replace  `const fs = middleware.fileSystem;` with promise for this issue?

Comment: Hi, I am using react boilerplate and getting the same error on this file. Could you share the solution you applied to resolve this error?

Comment: hi Bhawna. What webpack version you are using

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`webpack-dev-middleware` uses [memfs](https://github.com/streamich/memfs) as its default [outputFileSystem](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#outputfilesystem). `WDM` didn't expose the [API](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#api) so that you can **NOT** get the `outputFileSystem` from the instance of `WDM`. That's why you got that error.

You should create your own `outputfilesystem`, you can use the `memfs` to do that explicitly. Then, you can get the `index.html` from the memory file system.

You can use `util.promisify()` method from `util` Node.js built-in module to promisify the `fs.readFile` method.

E.g.

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html" })],
  mode: "development",
};
```

`app.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");
const util = require("util");
const express = require("express");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
const { createFsFromVolume, Volume } = require("memfs");
const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config");

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
const app = express();
const fs = createFsFromVolume(new Volume());
fs.join = path.join.bind(path);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

const middleware = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  stats: "errors-only",
  outputFileSystem: fs,
});
app.use(middleware);

app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = await readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, "index.html"));
    res.send(file.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!"));
```

Start the server:

```sh
⚡  node app.js                                                                                              
Example app listening on port 3000!
```

Access `http://localhost:3000/test`:

```sh
⚡  curl http://localhost:3000/test                                                <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
<script defer src="bundle.js"></script></head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

package version:

```json
{
  "name": "68618902",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "memfs": "^3.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

const util = require('util');
const {createFsFromVolume, Volume} = require('memfs');
const fs = createFsFromVolume(new Volume());
fs.join = path.join.bind(path);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

function createWebpackMiddleware(compiler, publicPath) {
    return webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
        publicPath,
        outputFileSystem: fs,
    });
}

module.exports = function addDevMiddlewares(app, webpackConfig) {
    const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
    const middleware = createWebpackMiddleware(compiler, webpackConfig.output.publicPath);

    app.use(middleware);
    app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

    app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const file = await readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html'));
            res.send(file.toString());
        } catch (error) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).